# Is every simplicial cancellative commutative monoid a Kan complex?

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Simplicial commutative monoids can fail to be Kan complexes. I don't know if this also fails assuming they are cancellative (the usual proof for simplicial groups does not seem to work). We say that a commutative monoid is cancellative (a.k.a. integral) if the map into its group completion is injective. So the question is:

Is every simplicial object in the category of cancellative commutative monoids a Kan complex?

Comment: Consider the 1-skeletal simplicial set whose 0-simplices are natural numbers with addition
and 1-simplices are pairs (a,b) where a=b or a+2≤b, with termwise addition.
This is a simplicial cancellative commutative monoid that is not Kan:
the horn (0,3),(1,3) does not have a filling (whose third edge would have to be (0,1), not an admissible pair).

Comment: (A related bit of not immediately relevant information:
algebraic theories whose simplicial algebras are always Kan are precisely those algebraic theories
that contain a Malcev operation.
Thus simplicial groups, simplicial torsors, etc. are always Kan, whereas simplicial monoids are not.
Cancellative commutative monoids do not form a variety of algebras, however.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Both comments are very helpful to me.